# Strip everything from an array of strings after certain character

Tags: string, julia

This rather simple julia issue has got me a little perplexed.

Let's say I have an array of strings of the form "xxx_xxx". Is there a function that will remove everything from "_" onward?

Example

```
names = ["last1_first1","last2_first2"]
```

Is there a simple function that will return

```
["last1","last2"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `split`:

```
julia> names  = ["last1_first1", "last2_first2"]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "last1_first1"
 "last2_first2"

julia> split.(names, "_")
2-element Array{Array{SubString{String},1},1}:
 ["last1", "first1"]
 ["last2", "first2"]
```

Note that I am using the dot broadcasting syntax `split.()` here to apply the `split` function elementwise to the array of names.

For completeness one way of pulling out the `last` elements is:

```
julia> hcat(split.(names, "_")...)[1, :]
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "last1"
 "last2"
```

As Cameron points out in the comments, if it is (as in this example) the first element you're after, you can replace the `hcat` and splatting with:

```
julia> first.(split.(names, "_"))
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "last1"
 "last2"
```

This is slightly less flexible for those cases where you want the `n`th index. For those cases you can broadcast `getindex` and pass it the index of the element you're after:

```
julia> julia> getindex.(split.(names, "_"), 2)
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "first1"
 "first2"
```

Alternatively building on the regex idea in your own answer, you can simply do:

```
julia> replace.(names, r"_.*" => "")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "last1"
 "last2"
```

Comment: Instead of the splatting and `hcat` business, how about `first.(split.(names, "_"))`?

Comment: Yes that's another option, albeit less general if you want the `n`-th element (unless you want to go down the `getindex.()` route.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this to be fast you can write:

```
(s -> s[1:prevind(s, findfirst('_', s))]).(names)
```

or if you want to be even faster:

```
(s -> SubString(s, 1, prevind(s, findfirst('_', s)))).(names)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the performance of your code 6x - 10x faster is:

```
SubString.(names,1,findfirst.(==('_'),names).-1)
```

Some benchmarks:

```
julia> using Random, BenchmarkTools

julia> const names=string.(randstring.(repeat([5],1000)),"_",randstring.(repeat([5],1000)));

julia> @btime  replace.(names, r"_.*" => "");
  264.801 μs (5002 allocations: 257.97 KiB)

julia> @btime hcat(split.(names, "_")...)[1, :];
  160.000 μs (4012 allocations: 243.05 KiB)

julia> @btime SubString.(names,1,findfirst.(==('_'),names).-1);
  26.599 μs (1001 allocations: 39.19 KiB)
```

If your text contains non ASCII characters you should use `prevind` instead of `.-1`

Answer (score 1):

I was just having some syntax issues

```
names[:] = map((x) -> replace(x,r"_.*",""),names[:])
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? This raises a `MethodError` for me. Also there's no need to enclose the `x` in your anonymous function in brackets, nor to index your array using `[:]`. So you could have written `map(x -> replace(x, r"_.*", ""), names)` to get the same effect.

Comment: The brackets around x were just a readability thing in my editor. The indexing of my array was actually because sometimes the data is given to me in odd formats (like a single column array of 2 dimensions) and indexing the array just picks out the column. Also not needed for my example here though!